# How to obtain centroidal momentum matrix?

Tags: drake

According to Whole-body Motion Planning with Centroidal Dynamics and Full Kinematics (Hongkai Dai, Andrés Valenzuela and Russ Tedrake)

[image]

Following the reference, one eventually arrives Resolved Momentum Control: Humanoid Motion Planning based on the Linear and Angular Momentum (Shuuji KAJITA, Fumio KANEHIRO, Kenji KANEKO, Kiyoshi FUJIWARA, Kensuke HARADA, Kazuhito YOKOI and Hirohisa HIRUKAWA)

[image]

Does drake currently provide any method for computing this centroidal momentum matrix `A(q)` or the `H` matrix (of which I believe `A(q) = [0, I_tilde, H]`)?

Comment: Judging by https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/10779, I would guess it's not yet implemented..

Comment: would you please take a look at the proposal in issue 10779 and let us know what would be most useful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull request [#13916](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/13916) was just merged today (October 2, 2020) and resolves issue [#10779](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/10779). For example, you can calculate spatial momentum — which contains both translational (linear) and rotational (angular) momentum with a command such as:

```
plant_.CalcSpatialMomentumInWorldAboutPoint(*context_, p_WoP_W);
```

There are more examples in the file:
[multibody/plant/test/multibody_plant_momentum_energy_test.cc](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/plant/test/multibody_plant_momentum_energy_test.cc)

Answer (score 1):

Later today, I'll take a look at this to see if there is an existing API -- or if one can be created relatively quickly.

Comment: Thanks Paul, much appreciated!